# Touchscreen and Driver Installed but tslib Cannot Calibrate

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux, touchscreen

I have cross-compiled the latest commit of tslib from github ( https://github.com/kergoth/tslib/commits/master ). My touchscreen is hooked up to my embedded board and I enabled the drivers from the vendor. When I boot and look at the output of 'cat /dev/input/touchscreen' I can see plenty of output being generated from moving my fingers around the screen. The Kernel also outputs to the console nicely formatted messages for 'finger1' and 'finger2'.

I am not able to calibrate however. When I set my environment variables like shown below and run ts_calibrate, it spits out the message 'xres = 640, yres = 480 tslib: Selected device is not a touchscreen (must support ABS and KEY event types)' and does nothing more...

So Linux knows that my device exists and I can see scrolling output, but tslib can't calibrate. What am I doing wrong and how can I fix this?

```
# ls -rlt /dev/input/touchscreen
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root             6 Jan 17 21:06 /dev/input/touchscreen -> event1
# chmod 777 /dev/input/touchscreen
# chmod 777 /dev/input/event1

# cat /dev/input/touchscreen  | hexdump
0000000 9011 3883 565f 0001 0003 0030 0001 0000
0000010 9011 3883 565f 0001 0003 0032 0001 0000
0000020 9011 3883 565f 0001 0003 0035 04c9 0000
0000030 9011 3883 565f 0001 0003 0036 0c3f 0000
0000040 9011 3883 565f 0001 0000 0002 0000 0000
0000050 9011 3883 565f 0001 0000 0000 0000 0000
0000060 9011 3883 90a9 0001 0003 0030 0001 0000
0000070 9011 3883 90a9 0001 0003 0032 0001 0000

# cat /sys/devices/virtual/input/input1/uevent
PRODUCT=0/0/0/0
NAME="aura-touchscreen"
PROP=0
EV=9
ABS=650000 0
MODALIAS=input:b0000v0000p0000e0000-e0,3,kra30,32,35,36,mlsfw

# cat /etc/ts.conf
# Uncomment if you wish to use the linux input layer event interface
module_raw input
module pthres pmin=1
module variance delta=30
module dejitter delta=100
module linear

export TSLIB_TSEVENTTYPE=INPUT
export TSLIB_TSDEVICE=/dev/input/touchscreen
export TSLIB_CALIBFILE=/etc/pointercal
export TSLIB_CONFFILE=/etc/ts.conf
export TSLIB_PLUGINDIR=/usr/lib/ts
export TSLIB_FBDEVICE=/dev/fb0
export TSLIB_CONSOLEDEVICE=none
export TSTS_INFO_FILE=/sys/devices/virtual/input/input1/uevent
export QWS_MOUSE_PROTO=tslib:/dev/input/touchscreen
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/bin
ts_calibrate
xres = 640, yres = 480
tslib: Selected device is not a touchscreen (must support ABS and KEY event types)
```

Interesting if I do 'cat /proc/bus/input/devices' then I can see my touchscreen but there is only an ABS entry ( no KEY ) and tslib says I need both. Can I somehow assign a 'KEY' entry here?

```
# cat /proc/bus/input/devices
I: Bus=0019 Vendor=0001 Product=0001 Version=0003
N: Name="TWL4030 Keypad"
P: Phys=twl4030_keypad/input0
S: Sysfs=/devices/platform/omap/omap_i2c.1/i2c-1/1-004a/twl4030_keypad/input/input0
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=kbd event0
B: PROP=0
B: EV=100013
B: KEY=ffc
B: MSC=10

I: Bus=0000 Vendor=0000 Product=0000 Version=0000
N: Name="aura-touchscreen"
P: Phys=
S: Sysfs=/devices/virtual/input/input1
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=event1
B: PROP=0
B: EV=9
B: ABS=650000 0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to add

```
input_dev = input_allocate_device();
[..]
set_bit(EV_ABS, input_dev->evbit);
set_bit(EV_KEY, input_dev->evbit);
```

So that the tslib sees the device as supporting both EV_ABS and EV_KEY events (even if it does not actually send both of those).

You know how to reach me if you have more questions... ;)

Comment: Thanks - I added the following to get ts_calibrate to not complain about the device not being a touchscreen:                          set_bit(EV_KEY, aura.input_dev->evbit);
set_bit(ABS_X, aura.input_dev->absbit);
set_bit(ABS_Y, aura.input_dev->absbit);
set_bit(BTN_TOUCH, aura.input_dev->keybit);
I am still working on getting ts_calibrate to accept input though.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same exact problem

```
tslib: Selected device is not a touchscreen (must support ABS and KEY event types)
```

I added

```
set_bit(EV_SYN, aura.input_dev->evbit);
set_bit(EV_ABS, aura.input_dev->evbit);
set_bit(EV_KEY, aura.input_dev->evbit);
# I had to add this line so that tslib was happy
```

in my touch screen driver but still having the same problem. I can't able to calibrate the touch screen. please give suggestion.

```
    static int goodix_ts_probe(struct i2c_client *client, const struct i2c_device_id *id)
{
    s32 ret = -1;
    struct goodix_ts_data *ts;
    u16 version_info;

    GTP_DEBUG_FUNC();
    set_bit(EV_SYN, aura.input_dev->evbit);
set_bit(EV_ABS, aura.input_dev->evbit);
set_bit(EV_KEY, aura.input_dev->evbit); # I had to add this line so that tslib was happy
    //do NOT remove these output log
    GTP_INFO("GTP Driver Version:%s",GTP_DRIVER_VERSION);
    GTP_INFO("GTP Driver build@%s,%s", __TIME__,__DATE__);
    GTP_INFO("GTP I2C Address:0x%02x", client->addr);

    i2c_connect_client = client;
    if (!i2c_check_functionality(client->adapter, I2C_FUNC_I2C)) 
    {
        GTP_ERROR("I2C check functionality failed.");
        return -ENODEV;
    }
    ts = kzalloc(sizeof(*ts), GFP_KERNEL);
    if (ts == NULL)
    {
        GTP_ERROR("Alloc GFP_KERNEL memory failed.");
        return -ENOMEM;
    }

    memset(ts, 0, sizeof(*ts));
    INIT_WORK(&ts->work, goodix_ts_work_func);
    ts->client = client;
    i2c_set_clientdata(client, ts);
    ts->irq_lock = SPIN_LOCK_UNLOCKED;
    ts->gtp_rawdiff_mode = 0;

    ret = gtp_request_io_port(ts);
    if (ret < 0)
    {
        GTP_ERROR("GTP request IO port failed.");
        kfree(ts);
        return ret;
    }

    ret = gtp_i2c_test(client);
    if (ret < 0)
    {
        GTP_ERROR("I2C communication ERROR!");
    }

#if GTP_AUTO_UPDATE
    //ret = gup_init_update_proc(ts);
    //if (ret < 0)
    //{
        //GTP_ERROR("Create update thread error.");
    //}
#endif

    ret = gtp_init_panel(ts);
    if (ret < 0)
    {
        GTP_ERROR("GTP init panel failed.");
    }

    ret = gtp_request_input_dev(ts);
    if (ret < 0)
    {
        GTP_ERROR("GTP request input dev failed");
    }

    ret = gtp_request_irq(ts); 
    if (ret < 0)
    {
        GTP_INFO("GTP works in polling mode.");
    }
    else
    {
        GTP_INFO("GTP works in interrupt mode.");
    }

    ret = gtp_read_version(client, &version_info);
    if (ret < 0)
    {
        GTP_ERROR("Read version failed.");
    }
    spin_lock_init(&ts->irq_lock);
    ts->irq_lock = SPIN_LOCK_UNLOCKED;

    gtp_irq_enable(ts);

#if GTP_CREATE_WR_NODE
    //init_wr_node(client);
#endif

#if GTP_ESD_PROTECT
    INIT_DELAYED_WORK(&gtp_esd_check_work, gtp_esd_check_func);
    gtp_esd_check_workqueue = create_workqueue("gtp_esd_check");
    queue_delayed_work(gtp_esd_check_workqueue, &gtp_esd_check_work, GTP_ESD_CHECK_CIRCLE); 
#endif

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This basically is a bug in old versions of tslib. A recent version should work without problems.